# How can I change only a specific option in a chart with chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have a `input` of type `number`, that gives me the `max ticks` on the `X-axis`.

I'm subscribed to the `valueChange` of that input, and the only way I found to update the `max` `value` of the tick option is:

```
updatedMaxTickX(chart: any, newMax: number): void {
        chart.options = {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            max: newMax
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
    }
```

and then:

```
this.detailsForm.get("max").valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
this.updatedMaxTickX(this.canvas, v);
this.canvas.update()
});
```

this works, the max Ticks get updated when the input changes, but what also happens is that all other options are reset!

so basically I think this overwrites my options and put everything else to default.

how can I only change the ticks.max while keeping everything else as defined in my controller?

I tried

```
this.detailsForm.get("max").valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
this.canvas.options.scales.xAxes.ticks.max = v;
this.canvas.update()
});
```

but this doesn't work and gives me errors.

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: @trichetriche TypeError: Cannot set property 'max' of undefined

Comment: This means you haven't set the `max` property the first time you have declared the options. Do it, and the last piece of code you have provided should work.

Comment: @trichetriche but if I just comment out that line and use in the same subscription the function I wrote above, that works, it just overwrites all the other settings

Comment: @trichetriche max is set to 0 in my xAxes tick options, so it's defined, I even tried other values, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xAxes` is an Array, this should work:

```
myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = v;
```